# ng-bootstrap datepicker calender icon is not displaying

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular-cli and ng-bootstrap for date picker. after installing datepicker from npm and adding it to main module, datepicker is working, However icon is not displaying.

[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7pip.png)

```
<div class="form-inline col-sm-6"> 
   <label class="col-sm-3">From:</label> 
   <div class="input-group"> 
      <input 
             class="form-control" 
             placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" 
             [(ngModel)]="model" 
              ngbDatepicker 
             #d="ngbDatepicker"> 
            <button 
                 class="input-group-addon" 
                 (click)="d.toggle()" 
                  type="button"> 
                   <img 
                        src="img/calendar-icon.svg" 
                        style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/> 
           </button> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is your code, how do you build it, and where have you put the image file in your project structure?

Comment: @JBNizet I haven't put the image file. I am just using html code

Comment: <div class="form-inline col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-3">From:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
        <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Post the relevant code, properly formatted, **in the question**, not in comments. `<img src="img/calendar-icon.svg"/>`: this is a simple HTML img tag looking for a calendar-icon.svg file on your server. If it's not there, how could an image be dispayed.

Comment: Thanks... I missed to place img folder in assets.

Answer (score 9):

If you open the [stackblitz](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/datepicker/popup/stackblitz.html) for one of their examples you can see they get the icon by adding this style:

```
button.calendar, button.calendar:active {
  width: 2.75rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 23px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Then just use something like this for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: Seems like an oversight from ng-bootstrap guys. They should really bundle a css together with their library so you can copy-paste their sample code and it all just works, instead of having to figure out what's going on

Answer (score 6):

Another option you can use [font awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css) and change the code of button tag to below-

```
<div class="input-group-append">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar fa fa-calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use css for the icon.

Documentation from ng-bootstrap:

> You must provide the icon for the button. This allows you to choose an
>   icon that matches your application's style. In this example, the icon
>   is set via a CSS class.

Reference for setting icon:

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_icons_datetime.asp

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue where we had the glyphicon classes on the button.  This worked for most use cases except when the datepicker was loaded from a ng-template.  The fix was to use the `<i>` element inside of the button like:

`<button (click)="toggleDatePicker($event)" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>`

instead of:

`<button tabindex="-1" (click)="toggleDatePicker($event)" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></button>`